# Create Generic List<T> Signature and Assign Object Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've an `Interface` where I am trying to create a generic `List<T>` and assign objects dynamically to it. Suppose as the following:

```
 public class Person
 {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
 }

 public interface IPerson
 {
    List<T> Get<T>() where T :  new();
 }
```

Finally I tried to do the following to pass the list of person object:

```
class aPerson : IPerson
{
  public List<Person> Get<Person>() //The constraints for type parameter 'Person' of method 'Program.aPerson.Get<Person>()' must match the constraints for type parameter 'T' of interface method 'Program.IPerson.Get<T>()'
  {
    List<Person> aLst = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person { id = "1001", name = "John" }, //Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'Person' because it does not have the new() constraint  
        new Person { id = "1002", name = "Jack" }
    };

    return aLst;
  }
}
```

I know, I am doing wrong here and expecting if someone could point out what could be the possible solution - Thanks.

Comment: `public interface IPerson
 {
    List<T> Get<T>() where T :  new();
 }` That is weird, especially since you have a separate (seemingly unrelated) `Person` class.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BPNM8g

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble understanding your object model. In plain words, what does it signify when a type implements `IPerson`? Right now, it means "The caller may specify any class and the IPerson will return a list of them."

Comment: i don't know why you try to use a generic for a specific case which is Person class , please give us more details about what you want to do ?

Comment: You are right, your modifications have just not been obvious.(easy to find).
To explain the error: public `List<Person> Get<Person>()` creates a new Generic Parameter named 'Person' and has the exact same meaning as List<T>.It has absolutely no relation to class Person. So it ends up in the Meaning of `new T { id = "1001" ...}` and that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using Generic Interface is incorrect, you can not the exact T type when you are implementing a generic Interface. In fact generic interfaces is a way of extending classes based interface you defined.

```
public interface IPerson<T>
{
    List<T> Get();
}

class aPerson : IPerson<Person>
{
    public List<Person> Get() 
    {
        var aLst = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person { id = "1001", name = "John" },
            new Person { id = "1002", name = "Jack" }
        };
        return aLst;
    }
}
```